# KVO. ObserveValueForKeyPAth is not called

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, key-value-observing

I am not if this will work properly

```
[[cr1.crossRoad.trafficLights 
    objectForKey: [NSNumber numberWithInt:pedestrianTL]] 
    addObserver:view 
    forKeyPath:@"colorState" 
    options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew 
    context:nil];
```

The project I'm developing doesn't work properly. This way I was trying to add an observer to change the view with after every change happening to the cell of the colorState array.

```
-(void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context{
    [self refreshState:object];
}
```

The program never enters this method though I change values of the colorState cells. Maybe the problem is with me trying to observe array but not actually what it contains?

Comment: Are you sure that the call to `objectForKey` is returning anything?  Break down the statement to make inspection easier via the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was trying to observe an array which was not possible that way.